# SQL - Evaluate Record Over A Partition Using Window Functions

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions

The below data is at the trip level, a unique trip per row. I'm looking to set a 0 / 1 boolean when the same person has RETURNED to the same location, meaning their first trip to a destination will not have the 1 indicator. Ideally, I can do this with a window function but am open to other thoughts if we cannot compare a value within a partition against all of the other values within partition.

My initial attempt only compared against one record within the partition and won't pick up if they went back to the same Destination on a trip beyond their next one.

My initial attempt was:
CASE WHEN Destination = LAG(Destination) OVER (PARTITION BY Person) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END

**STARTING DATA EXAMPLE BELOW**

| Person | Trip | Destination |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | a | Hawaii |
| Bob | b | Hawaii |
| Bob | c | Florida |
| Kevin | a | Texas |
| Kevin | b | Iowa |
| Tina | a | Arizona |
| Tina | b | Arizona |
| Tina | c | California |
| Tina | d | New Mexico |
| Tina | e | Arizona |
| Tina | e | California |

**DESIRED OUTPUT BELOW**

| Person | Trip | Destination | Same_Destination |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | a | Hawaii | 0 |
| Bob | b | Hawaii | 1 |
| Bob | c | Florida | 0 |
| Kevin | a | Texas | 0 |
| Kevin | b | Iowa | 0 |
| Tina | a | Arizona | 0 |
| Tina | b | Arizona | 1 |
| Tina | c | California | 0 |
| Tina | d | New Mexico | 0 |
| Tina | e | Arizona | 1 |
| Tina | f | California | 1 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify your condition to use `first_value`:

```
case when 
  destination = First_Value(destination) over(partition by person order by trip rows unbounded preceeding) 
    and trip != First_Value(trip) over(partition by person order by trip rows unbounded preceeding)
then 1 else 0 end
```

Edit

Based on your addition comments I think this would be simpler to implement using a correlated subquery. Does the following work for you?

```
select *, case when exists (
    select * from t t2 
    where t2.person = t.person 
      and t2.destination = t.destination 
      and t2.trip < t.trip
) then 1 else 0 end
from t;
```

Comment: `ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING` might be wise, both for performance and correctness reasons

Comment: Rows unbounded preceeding and current row is the default if not specified, is there a tangible performance benefit?

Comment: @Stu thank you for editing and the quick answer. Your solution works perfectly when comparing the first trip against all of the trips in a partition! I adjusted my example data as it's not quite what was desired. I'm hopin to evaluate all trips within the partition. For example, with "Tina" above, if she went back to California, we would also denote that subsequent California trip with a 1.

Comment: No it's not, the default is `RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING` which is subtly different. See https://stevestedman.com/2013/04/rows-and-range-preceding-and-following/ and https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/databases/sql-server/t-sql-programming-sql-server/introduction-to-t-sql-window-functions/

Comment: @CarsonWhitley I have amended in the answer above with an alternative.